# How to merge excel file and svg file

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf

I am using PDF Creator v1.2 to merge an Excel and SVG file. I put them both in a print queue one after the other and use the CombineAll option to combine them. But sometimes I get an Adobe Illustrator error (error code - 289).

Answer (score 0):

is there a reason you can't convert the SVG file to PDF then merge them?

I know if you are using [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) you can export to pdf. then I would export the .xls(x) to pdf then merge them...

hope that helps